# How do you round a UISlider to an int in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I was wondering how to round a UISilder value to a int value. Right now it is displaying floats. I am using swift 3 at the moment.

```
     @IBOutlet var slidermove: UISlider!

     @IBAction func SliderVal(_ sender: AnyObject) {

         print(slidermove)
         let x = round(slidermove)
  }
```

round() does not work it will give an error, thanks for anyone that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should round it's value instead of UISlider itself.:

```
let x = roundf(slider.value) // x is Float
```

If you need an `Int` instead of `Float`, just wrap it with Int initializer:

```
let x = Int(round(slider.value)) // x is Int
```

Comment: Thank you alex for your help it worked!. But how would i get rid that last decimal point. e.g 10.0 to 10

Comment: @Puneet You're welcome. Have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

To round a `Float` to the nearest integer and get the result as
an `Int`, the (perhaps not so well-known) function [`lrintf()`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/lrint.3.html)
can be used. Example:

```
let x = Float(12.6)
let i = lrintf(x)
print(i) // 13
```

In your case:

```
let i = lrintf(slider.value) // `i` is an `Int`
```

Comment: Thank you Martin R

Comment: @Puneet: There was an error because the slider value is a Float, not a Double. That is fixed now.